# Using three variables at same time to specify value in array with Twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, variables, twig, template-engine

I have two arrays: teachers_number_array which contains the id of teachs and the another array 'teachers' witch contains the data of each teacher.

What I can't do is to show the name of a specific teacher based on its id:

```
{% for teachers_number in teachers_number_array %}
    {% if teachers_number in teachers|keys %}
        {{ teachers.teachers_number.name }} 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{ teachers[teachers_number].name }} ` or `attribute(teachers, teacher_number).name)`

Comment: Did you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Note that you can get the key of the array directly in the Twig loop (`for id, teacher in teachers`):

PHP variables:

```
$teachers_to_display = [2, 3];
$teachers =  [
    1 => 'Fabien',
    2 => 'COil',
    3 => 'Tokeeen',
    'do not display' => 'Nooooo',
];
```

Twig:

```
{% for id, teacher in teachers %}
    {% if id in teachers_to_display %}
        {{ teacher }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Will output:

- COil
- Tokeeen

PS: If you have several properties just use `teacher.name` like you did before:

```
$teachers =  [
    1 => [
        'name' => 'Pot',
        'firstname' => 'Fabien',
...
```